# Unable to create the correct link with vue router-link

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I am using the vue rounter-link tag to navigate to a different page. My problem is that it does not seem to navigate to a different page. I think the problem lies within the "params" of the router-link. I do have a blog_id as 2 but it always shows the current page blog_id that I am at.

Initially I have

```
<router-link v-bind:to="{name:'datascience-single', params: {blog_id: blog.blog_id}}">
    <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</router-link>
```

but then I started to think that maybe it's not taking the blog.blog_id correctly so I replaced it with a fixed value

```
        <li v-for="blog in blogs" v-bind:key="blog.id">
          <h1>{{blog.title}}</h1>
          {{blog.content}}
          <router-link v-bind:to="{name:'datascience-single', params: {blog_id: 2}}">
            <i class="fa fa-cogs" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          </router-link>
        </li>
```

However the problem remains the same.

Answer (score 0):

This answer assumes you are already on the same route you are navigating to.

Navigating to the same route does not refresh your components. We are used that whenever we go to a different URL the page should refresh, with multipage websites. However Vue router handles this differently. For the router the route,  eg: `/blogs/{id}`, is not changing whenever `id` is being updated, we are still on `/blogs/{id}` but with a different parameter.

In order to detect this change we can simply make a watcher on the route parameter:

```
watch: {
    '$route.params.id': (id) => {
        // The route is the same, but our parameter changed.
    }
}
```